# Receive large binary data from socket in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, binary, electron

I would like to receive binary data (like .pdf or .doc) from a tcp socket, here is the code :

To send the file :

```
fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
  var client = new net.Socket();
    client.connect(user_port, user_ip, function () {
      client.write(data, 'binary');
      client.destroy();
    });
});
```

To receive the file :

```
net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.setEncoding('binary');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        var file_data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
        fs.appendFile(utils.getUserDir() + '/my_file.doc', file_data);
    });
    socket.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    })
}).listen(utils.getPort(), utils.getExternalIp());
```

As the files are too big for only one tcp socket, they are sent with multiples packets, in fact there is multiple 'data' event for the same file.
I thought it was possible to append each `Buffer()` data to a file, but when I open the .doc, he is corrupted or has binary things in it.

PS: I can't use `Buffer().concat` and save the file after since I don't know which packet is the last one...

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sending files like this, it's better to stream them instead of buffer it all into memory and then sending it. (Also, you don't need the `'binary'` encoding argument since `fs.readFile()` gives you a Buffer by default)

For example:

```
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(user_port, user_ip, function() {
  fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(client);
});

// ...

net.createServer(function(socket){
  socket.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(utils.getUserDir() + '/my_file.doc'));
  socket.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err.message);
  });
}).listen(utils.getPort(), utils.getExternalIp());
```